# Prevent Windows 10 from switching the default audio device when a new one is plugged in

Tags: windows, audio

The scenario:

This is how my audio setup looks like:

- A headset which I use as default audio device (input & output)
- An USB camera that supports audio input apart from video, which I plug in only when I need
- OS is Windows 10 Pro with last available build installed at this moment (I'm not a Windows Insider member)
- No third party software is in use, not even the USB camera manufacturer's one nor the headset's one

The problem:

As soon as I plug in the USB camera (no matter on which port) Windows instantly switches the "default communication device" (AND "default audio device") to the USB Camera microphone instead of keeping the headset input as the default one (and as I manually have to set every single time).

Expected behaviour:

To keep my headset as default communication device no matter what additional device is plugged into the computer.

Useless/discarded workarounds:

After digging up for answers in the official Microsoft forum I unfortunately did not find any reply that could effectively prevent this from happening again and again. These are some of the threads asking for the same issue:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-automatic-switch-to-plugged-in-audio/afd9b134-b87a-4701-9714-6964a3e295c4
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-stop-windows-from-automatically-switching/b6b7c197-3391-440b-ab02-018e51234583
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-stop-windows-from-automatically-switching/9c581325-a71f-48e4-b13b-0995f07b9b32
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-prevent-audio-output-to-automatically/f587ef99-30b7-4237-8dbf-65b2732d96e7

Also I have already seen that there is another question very similar to this one in SuperUser, but unluckily no one replied to it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60818414/disable-switching-default-audio-device

Additional info:

I have already discarded that there may be a driver problem (as many of the official Microsoft replies point in their answers to the same question in the related threads as first workaround). I can tell as long as this behaviour keeps happening no matter what kind of extra audio device is plugged into the computer (already tried with external USB sound cards, in-ear headphones, and so on) that it will become the default one.

The question:

At this point I would appreciate any kind of guidance or workaround regarding this issue.

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: some progress, yes! stackoverflow removed the other question. propably because someone thought it was to generic, because he/she did not even understand the problem. since when do microsoft helpdesk employees work for stackoverflow?